# Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I'm trying to get my MySQL data to Excel file, but I'm having problems with Excel cells. All my text goes to one cell, I would like to have each row value in separate Excel cell. Here is my code:

```
$queryexport = ("
SELECT username,password,fullname FROM ecustomer_users
WHERE fk_customer='".$fk_customer."'
");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryexport);

$result = mysql_query($queryexport);
$header = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
   $header .= mysql_field_name($result, $i)."\t";
   }

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   $line = '';
   foreach($row as $value){
          if(!isset($value) || $value == ""){
                 $value = "\t";
          }else{
                 $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                 $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                 }
          $line .= $value;
          }
   $data .= trim($line)."\n";
   $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);

if ($data == "") {
   $data = "\nno matching records found\n";
   }
}
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// output data
echo $header."\n".$data;

mysql_close($conn);`
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should really use an array to build the lines of your file. Then you just have to use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to glue the elements together. This saves you the hassle of having to check if your current line buffer is empty or not when you want to append the delimiter.

Comment: @Miklos - why use implode? PHP provides the built-in function fputcsv() for writing CSV/TSV/etc files

Comment: @Mark thanks for the heads-up, PHP is not my main skill so I didn't know about that function.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

***Just Try With The Following :***

**PHP Part :**

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "databasename";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tablename"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: He is clearly asking excel not a csv solution. Also for a CSV file you must use application/csv or text/csv content-type not application/vnd.ms-excel (At least that is the standard for CSV files.)

Comment: One more thing even CSV solution is ok, There are no need to use PHP for generate a csv from mysql table. It can be generated by sql statement `SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;`

Comment: @JohnPeter I tried using the code but when I run the page all it does is output the contents of the table into the web browser. I am setting the $filename variable to "testfile", could this be where I am going wrong? Also, where does this code output the excel file to? Do I need to specify the directory in the $filename variable?

Comment: @JohnPeter : Thanks for the code above, This works good, but what if I want only selected column(with changed custom-column name ) to be exported in the excel sheet? I am stuck with that. I would not like my user to know the name of the column name and the encrypted password stored in the user table.

Comment: I got the solution ---  $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
echo "Name" . "\t";
echo "Email" . "\t";
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo $row[1] . "\t";;
        echo $row[2] . "\t";
        print "\n";
    }   
?>

Comment: I also tried this code, it is working when i check in console but not downloading. Pls help me. I dont know why it is not downloading.

Comment: How do i protect above excel download ? If i use session then browser print all the data instead download as excel

Comment: @JohnPeter This Code is working fine but converting values, formulas, dates of MQSQL Table etc in Excel results like solving the formula and changing the formats But I need to save simple like text so is this possible in this code?

Comment: maybe i am doing something wrong, but its printing the results to my firefox browser. no file download prompt comes up. everyone else seems to be having success with it so done know.

Comment: Tried it on google chrome as well, same issue. it's printing the results to browser

Comment: Is its possible to do same thing for XLSX files exporting.....
what is _Content-Type_ for xlsx?

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya : For xlsx try with the following : $file = "myfile.xlsx";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush(); 
readfile($file);

Comment: doesn't works cause isn't xls it's csv
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats

Answer (score 17):

Try this code. It's definitly  working.

```
<?php
// Connection 

$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db=mysql_select_db('excel',$conn);

$filename = "Webinfopen.xls"; // File Name
// Download file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$user_query = mysql_query('select name,work from info');
// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: When I use this code it works perfectly, however it also writes the whole web page to the file. Any idea why?

Comment: Use PHPExcel library for better solution of excel sheet export import

Comment: You can add at the end of your while : die();

It will stop the loading of your page, content should no longer be displayed

Comment: definitly not =\

Comment: I have Asked Question, Can You Give me reputation for asking question and flag it as helpful?

Answer (score 12):

If you just want your query data dumped into excel I have to do this frequently and using an html table is a very simple method. I use mysqli for db queries and the following code for exports to excel:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");


echo '<table border="1">';
//make the column headers what you want in whatever order you want
echo '<tr><th>Field Name 1</th><th>Field Name 2</th><th>Field Name 3</th></tr>';
//loop the query data to the table in same order as the headers
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['field1']."</td><td>".$row['field2']."</td><td>".$row['field3']."</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: wow, that's working....but when opening it after the download, the excel shows a warning that the extension and content do not match so the data may be corrupted.

Comment: add `exit();` after `echo '</table>';` if you got your page's unnecessary content too in export..

Answer (score 11):

This is new version of php code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "your_dbname";
//mysql and db connection

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {  //error check
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else
{

}


$DB_TBLName = "your_table_name"; 
$filename = "excelfilename";  //your_file_name
$file_ending = "xls";   //file_extention

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.'.'.$file_ending");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$sep = "\t";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName"; 
$resultt = $con->query($sql);
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field name
    echo $property->name."\t";
}

print("\n");    

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultt))  //fetch_table_data
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j< mysqli_num_fields($resultt);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat, You are most welcome and my pleasure to help something

Answer (score 10):

PHPExcel is your friend. Very easy to use and works like a charm.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Deprecated, as stated on their own Github page.

Comment: @acidrums4: You can use PhpSpreadsheet instead. It's the successor of PHPExcel: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try with this API

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/source/browse/trunk/php-excel.class.php

With This

```
Create a quick export from a database table into Excel

Compile some statistical records with a few calculations and deliver
the result in an Excel worksheet

Gather the items off your (web-based) todo list, put them in a
worksheet and use it as a foundation for some more statistics
magic.**
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hasil-export.xls");

    include 'view-lap.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code

data.php

```
    <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>NO.</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>Major</th>
</tr>
<?php
//connection to mysql
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //server , username , password
mysql_select_db("codelution");

//query get data
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY id ASC");
$no = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$no.'</td>
        <td>'.$data['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['major'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
    $no++;
}
?>
```

code for excel file

export.php

```
<?php
// The function header by sending raw excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
// Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=codelution-export.xls");
// Add data table
include 'data.php';
?>
```

if mysqli version

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user_details";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $no = 1;
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {echo '
    <tr>
        <<td>'.$no.'</td>
        <td>'.$data['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['major'].'</td>

    </tr>
    ';
    $no++;
```

http://codelution.com/development/web/easy-ways-to-export-data-from-mysql-to-excel-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

You can export the data from MySQL to Excel by using this simple code.

```
<?php
include('db_con.php');


$stmt=$db_con->prepare('select * from books');
$stmt->execute();


$columnHeader ='';
$columnHeader = "Sr NO"."\t"."Book Name"."\t"."Book Author"."\t"."Book 
ISBN"."\t";


$setData='';

while($rec =$stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $rowData = '';
 foreach($rec as $value)
 {
  $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
  $rowData .= $value;
 }
 $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";
}


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Book record 
sheet.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";

?>
```

complete code here [php export to excel](http://www.phpcodify.com/export-data-to-excel-in-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Posts by John Peter and Dileep kurahe helped me to develop what I consider as being a simpler and cleaner solution, just in case anyone else is still looking.  (I am not showing any database code because I actually used a $_SESSION variable.)

The above solutions invariably caused an error upon loading in Excel, about the extension not matching the formatting type.  And some of these solutions create a spreadsheet with the data across the page in columns where it would be more traditional to have column headings and list the data down the rows.  So here is my simple solution:

```
$filename = "webreport.csv";
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
foreach($results as $x => $x_value){
    echo '"'.$x.'",' . '"'.$x_value.'"' . "\r\n";
}
```

1. Change to .csv (which Excel instantly updates to .xls and there is no error upon loading.)
2. Use the comma as delimiter.
3. Double quote the Key and Value to escape any commas in the data.
4. I also prepended column headers to `$results` so the spreadsheet looked even nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following Code Please.
just only update two values.
1.your_database_name
2.table_name

```
 <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="your_database_name";
    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$dbname); 

        $sql_data="select * from table_name";
        $result_data=$con->query($sql_data);
        $results=array();
    filename = "Webinfopen.xls"; // File Name
    // Download file
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_data)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is baes on John Peter's answer above. The code is working perfectly but I needed it for WordPress. So, I did something like this:

```
<?php

require '../../../wp-load.php';

$file_name = "registered-users";
$args = array( 'role' => 'client',
   'meta_query' => array( array(
       'key' => '_dt_transaction_archived',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
   ) ),
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'orderby' => 'ID'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
$file_ending = "xls";

// Header info for browser
header( "Content-Type: application/xls" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.$file_ending" );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
header( "Expires: 0" );

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

// define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
// start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

print( "First Name" . $sep );
print( "Last Name" . $sep );
print( "E-Mail" . $sep );
print( "\n" );
// end of printing column names

// start foreach loop to get data
$schema_insert = "";

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ( $user ) {
        $schema_insert = "$user->first_name" . $sep;
        $schema_insert .= "$user->last_name" . $sep;
        $schema_insert .= "$user->user_email" . $sep;
        print "\n";
        $schema_insert = str_replace( $sep . "$", "", $schema_insert );
        $schema_insert = preg_replace( "/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert );
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print( trim( $schema_insert ) );
    }
}
```