# how to export the selected data into excel format when i click the link

Tags: php, excel

how to save a selected data in excel format in php when i click the link? and i want to save the file in the location given at the run time of the file? please advice me..

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');   //define header info for browser
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename='.$dbTable.'-'.date('Ymd').'.xls');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
```

Comment: please search before posting , [export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php) and for select just post checkboxes or other means of selecting via post and use in WHERE clause of query

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $dbTable.'-'.date('Ymd') . ".xls\"");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Or simply :

```
header("Location: http://path/to/file/filename.xlsx");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```

Comment: I think he does not have a xls file on the server yet and wants to generate it with php from data selected by user from browser ...

Comment: If this is the case, then using this library : https://phpexcel.codeplex.com is my best bet . It's extremely easy to custom excel files. After the file is created with the proper name, he can use the examples above

Comment: maybe give us the form fields and i can give you an example using the php excel class

Comment: It all depends on what do you want exactly, and what do you currently have. If you want to create the XLS based on form fields, please give us the form , so i can give you an example. If you already have the XLS created, you can use the code i already wrote.