# Syncing data from phpmyadmin/mysql to onedrive

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure if this is exactly what I'm looking for but I have a form in html and PHP and when it is submitted it submits it to a table in phpmyadmin. I want to take that data and put it on something like onedrive and have it be easy to view, like in excel. If anyone knows how to do this it would be awesome!

Comment: Embedding something like Google Form could make it easier if you are open to use such things.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little bit late for a reply, but as I understand, you have MySQL and PHP running on the web-server which "hosts" your Form.

There are several options available to you:

1. If you really insist on using OneDrive for your "synchronization" purposes, then OneDrive actually offers [API](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm). When processing your Form inputs, after you have sent the query to MySQL for CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE, you could each time create the database dump and import it into a new Excel file - [Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php). Subsequently you can use OneDrive API to upload the file to OneDrive.
2. There is such a thing as [MySQL for Excel](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/excel/1.3.html). I have not personally tried it, but it seems to be just the tool you are looking for!
3. Personally, I would use a web-based approach to Database management. PHPMyAdmin does offer direct MySQL management, but it's not usable in day-to-day business management. I would recommend using an MVC Framework such as [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) along with Grid View extensions such as [this one](http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo), which has "Export to Excel" feature from the box.

Hope this helps!