# PHP & MySQL to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

As title already specifies I need to send data from MySQL to excel via PHP with some filtering i.e. value greater than 0.

I have fond [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php) which works great...

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "databasename";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tablename"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

... how ever when I have tried to separate the require values i.e greater than 0 I get nothing. What I have try to do is as follows:

I have added this `if ($row["row_name"] > "0" )` just after `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){` which worked fine in another example that I have but this time with no luck. Any pointers should be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: ^ This. Also, I would suggest looking into using PHPOffice/PHPExcel or PHPOffice/PHPSpreadsheet (newer)

Comment: Do you have a column `row_name` in your table?

Comment: @Jens Yes I do have the column with that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))` to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` then add `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to cut out the PHP piece with MySQL for Excell  https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/