# header("Content-Disposition: attachment) not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, export-to-excel, lamp

I have tried to export the mysql data result to excel. After click the `Export` button, the form will send parameter's value into `doexport.php`.
The result was appeared in console.

[image]

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
include('install_lang_japanese.php');

//connect to database
$dbc=mysqli_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD,"QPL");
if(!$dbc){
   die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
   switch($_POST['action']){
      case 'senddatacar':

         $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['startdate']);
         $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['enddate']);

         $sqlex = "SELECT * FROM table";
         $result =mysqli_query($dbc,$sqlex) or die(_ERROR30.":".mysqli_error($dbc));

         $filename="cardata".date('ymd').".xls";

         header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
         header(sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"));
         header("Pragma: no-cache");
         header("Expires: 0");

         //Then echo table
         break;
    }
mysqli_close($dbc);
}
```

My problem is : i don't see any file has downloaded as excel

---

Response Header at console :

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=cardata170929.xls
Content-Length:2988
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'
Date:Fri, 29 Sep 2017 05:02:19 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: do you want real excel? or just a csv? simply naming some file *.xls, does not magically make it a valid excel file. but unless you have specific requirements for excel, a csv is far more compatible

Comment: You need to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php

Comment: @rtfm so you mean better i change it to csv file?

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid I have following that code, but i can't see any file downloaded.

Comment: well that depends what you want, which i dont know.

Comment: @rtfm i have update my post. actually i could echo the mysql in `<div>` but no file downloaded.