# Export SQL database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to make a button on the HTML page that exports SQL DB  from phpMyAdmin and put the data in excel sheet.
The Problem is  I can't find the way to do that. 
I want to implement it using  PHP or JS

Comment: Welcome to SO, we provide help to problems that already have been attempted by yourself. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You don't say what language or libraries you want to use to do this. That is, what will run when this button is clicked? Some sort of PHP? Javascript? Then, what will it do? Is there a PHPMyAdmin API you can call, or do you have to simulate clicks and gestures? Break the problem down into pieces and solve those first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php)

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL client. You want to select some data from a table or view in your MySQL database and have it put in an excel file that is then downloaded by the user? OR are you wanting to edit the phpmyadmin files to put this button on it's interface?  Either way this is too broad for SO and there are TON of how-to's online for this.

Comment: @JNevill i want to put the DB in excel sheet and download it
but  i want the user to do it not from phpmy admin

Comment: This may help: [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)