# How to extract all data from sql table and save it in excel file in codeigniter using SimpleXLSX

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to get all the data from mysql table and save it in Excel format using SimpleXLSX library and let the user download that excel format. I have use that library before for importing data from excel file but now i want it for exporting from mysql database to Excel Format.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have found this link where we can save sql data in excel file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699301/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php but i want to know can i use SimpleXLSX Library for that because i have used it before in the same project to import data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only `SimpleXLSX.php` - it's impossible. [example source](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx/tree/master/src)

If you're using additional files like `SimpleXLSXStyle.php, SimpleXLSXWorkbook.php, SimpleXLSXWorksheet.php` - you could [save](https://github.com/emikhalev/SimpleXLSX/blob/master/examples/sample.php) it in some directory and then retrieve it(create, save into temp dir, retrieve, delete from temp dir). [example source](https://github.com/emikhalev/SimpleXLSX/tree/master/src)

The final answer it's possible or not would be done after researching of the SimpleXLSX library files in your project.